# Does gevent have a 64-bit version?

Tags: python, django, gevent

When I deploy a dJango project, I get the error:

```
lib/gevent/core.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32.
```

What's wrong here? Does gevent have 64bit version?

I just set a website for fun, using django to build a chatroom, fault details: http://www.milkwall.com/rooms/

Comment: We have no idea what you mean by deploy. You haven't given enough information here about your process. Where did you first set this up? Where are you "deploying" it and what is different about their environments? If you give more information, I can update my answer further.

Comment: I just set a website for fun, using django to build a chatroom, fault details: http://www.milkwall.com/rooms/

Answer (score -1):

**If you build gevent for 64-bit, then it will be 64-bit.**

I, for instance, have a fat binary i386/x86_64 on OSX, when I installed it through homebrew.

You are probably combining mixed architectures. Either you are using different python interpreters between your deployment, or mixed site-packages. Its not clear what your deploy process is, but if you are copying binary's in addition to your pure python, then its quite possible that it will cause you problems. You are hopefully deploying by means of building your project clean on the destination machine.

Comment: I just set a website for fun, using django to build a chatroom, fault details: http://www.milkwall.com/rooms/

Comment: Where can I get or download a fat binary i386/x86_64 gevent?

Comment: Download the the source and build it. Homebrew for osx simply downloads it and uses a recipe to build it. It should be extremely easy for u to do it on linux manually

Comment: I'm not clear why this was downvoted. Would the downvoter care to comment? My answer covered the fact that I have a 64-bit gevent, as a result of it being built for that arch.